# jQueryUI.DatePicker How to change Date in format dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

jQueryUI.DatePicker How to change Date in format `mm/dd/yyyy` to `dd/mm/yyyy` ?
How I do formate date in format `dd/mm/yyyy` using Data-Picker?
I´m using `$(".selector").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' })` but doesn't works.

I added these link;

```
<script src="date/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="date/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="date/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="date/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
      $(".date").datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true
       });
     });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" 
  SkinID = "txtboxCustomizedMSkin" AutoPostBack = "True" OnTextChanged 
  = "txtStartDate_TextChanged" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" CssClass="date">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the `dateFormat` option to `dd/mm/yy`, note that `yy` stands for 4 digit year

```js
$(function() {
  $(".date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="txtStartDate" class="date" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" />
```